# Apache spark jdbc connect to apache drill error

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-drill

I am sending query to apache drill from apache spark. I am getting the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Failed to create prepared statement: PARSE
>   ERROR: Encountered "\"" at line 1, column 23.

When traced, I found I need to write a custom sql dialect. The problem I do not find any examples for pyspark. All the examples are for scala or java. Any help is highly appreciated.!

Here is the pyspark code :

```
`dataframe_mysql = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:drill:zk=ip:2181;schema=dfs").option("driver","org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable","dfs.`/user/titanic_data/test.csv`").load()`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I navigated to the drill web ui and updated the `planner.parser.quoting_identifiers` parameter to `"`. Then I edited my query as below:

```
dataframe_mysql = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:drill:zk=ip:2181;schema=dfs;").option("driver","org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable","dfs.\"/user/titanic_data/test.csv\"").load()
```

And it worked like charm!

Comment: There is more elegant solution without using Drill Web UI. You can specify the necessary identifier quote symbol in connection string. So the option method will be in your case: `.option("url", "jdbc:drill:zk=ip:2181;schema=dfs;quoting_identifiers=\"")`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have used a double quote in your SQL query (please share your SQL).

By default Drill uses back tick for quoting identifiers  - ` 
But you can change it by setting the system/session option (when you are already connected to Drill by JDBC for example) or you can specify it in JDBC connecting string. You can find more information here:
https://drill.apache.org/docs/lexical-structure/#identifier-quotes